# Create a multiple child object for XML from CSV file in JAVA - JAXB Marshalling

Tags: java, xml, csv, jaxb, marshalling

I have a program that transform my `CSV` file to `XML` file.

based on my `XSD` each `UserID` can have multiple `Detail` object

This is the result I expect

```
<XML>  
  <Plant>
        <UserID>37686</UserID>
        <Verification>
            <Detail>
                <Number>4851</Number>
                <IPF>2</IPF>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <Number>9978</Number>
                <IPF>2</IPF>
            </Detail>
            <Detail>
                <Number>9994</Number>
                <IPF>2</IPF>
            </Detail>
        </Verification>
        <PointNumber>0</PointNumber>
        <Length>127.9</Length>
   </Plant>
   <Plant>
        <UserID>11111</UserID>
        <Verification>
            <Detail>
                <Number>9994</Number>
                <IPF>2</IPF>
            </Detail>
        </Verification>
        <PointNumber>0</PointNumber>
        <Length>0</Length>
   </Plant>
<XML>
```

And this is my CSv file

```
User ID; Number; IPF;PointNumber; Length
37686;4851;2;0;127.9
37686;9978;2;0;0
37686;9994;2;0;0
11111;9994;2;0;0
```

I want to loop on each row and control the `UserID`, If it is equal to the previous one, it should not create ma another `Plant` object and need to insert just the second and third value as a `Detail` Object to the previous `UserID`

This is my code, but I can not achieve it.

```
String[] prevvalue = null;
 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {   
                    
                    Start++;
                    String[] currentvalue;
                    String Cur = null;
                     currentvalue =line.split(";");
                    Detail Detail = new Detail();
                    ArrayList<Detail> DetailList = new ArrayList();

                    Plant Plant = new Plant();   
                    if (Start >0 && prevvalue!= null) {
                       Cur = currentvalue[0];
                        
                        if (Cur.equals(prevvalue)) {
                            
                            Detail.setNumber(currentvalue[1]);
                            Detail.setIPF(currentvalue[2]); 
                        }
                       elseif (Cur!= prevvalue) {
                            Plant.setUserID(currentvalue[0]);
                            Plant.setPointNumber(currentvalue[3]);
                            impianto.setLength(currentvalue[4]);
                            
                            Detail.setNumber(currentvalue[1]);
                            Detail.setIPF(currentvalue[2]); 
                        }
                        
                    }
                DetailList.add(Detail);
                Plant.setDetail(Detaillist);
                PlantList.add(Plant) ;
                prevvalue = currentvalue[0];
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this?
Regards
Sin

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution...
My mistakes was in the definition of my Objects, I had defined them inside the loop, But some of them have to be defined inside, the other outside.

Thanks again